# C# wpf mvvm datagrid edit cells

Tags: c#, datagrid, edit

When I edit a cell, I want to retrieve the content of that cell into a string object in my viewModel?

How do I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to validate the input? What is ItemsSource of DataGrid? Is it a DataTable in ViewModel?

Comment: Could you provide more context on what you're doing, perhaps? There is likely a way to do what you're asking, but there might be a better way to handle your situation. For example, if you're ultimately just wanting to update the objects that are bound to the grid, this can happen automatically. Just need to know what you're wanting :)

Answer (score 0):

If the editing is in datagrid than we could retrieve the item in the current cell by using a property.

The property is :

```
private <YourObject> datagridselectedItem;

public <YourObject> DatagridselectedItem
    {
        get { return datagridselectedItem; }
        set
        {
            datagridselectedItem = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DatagridselectedItem");
        }
    }
```

Let me know whether it is helpful to you.